# How to implement react-autosuggest to load suggestions in "input-focus"?

Tags: reactjs, input

I want to all the suggestions on "input-focus" and when the user further types the text so also the suggestions will appear in **react-autosuggest**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import "./styles.css";
import Autosuggest from "react-autosuggest";
import { useState } from "react";

const options = ["Suggestion 1", "Suggestion 2", "Suggestion 3"];

export default function App() {
  const [s, setS] = useState(options);
  const [x, setX] = useState("Suggestion 1");
  const [y, setY] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autosuggest
        inputProps={{
          value: x,
          onChange: (event, { newValue }) => {
            setX(newValue);
          },
          onFocus: () => {
            setY(true);
          },
          onBlur: () => {
            setY(false);
          }
        }}
        suggestions={s}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={({ value }) => {
          setS(options.filter((x) => x.includes(value)));
        }}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={() => {
          setS([]);
        }}
        renderSuggestion={(text: string) => {
          return <>{text}</>;
        }}
        getSuggestionValue={(a) => {
          return a;
        }}
        alwaysRenderSuggestions={y}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dubinsky-3hust?file=/src/App.tsx). HTH.

Comment: That's really great tweak. Thank you for that. But one thing i also want to implement on this to load all the matching suggestions when user type something.

Comment: @Asit I have updated the answer with new code and new link.

Comment: @Asit If you find my answer useful, please consider voting it and/or marking it as accepted with the buttons on the left side of it.